# WSProxy Retrieve Ordered Rows

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, wsproxy

There is a way to return ordered rows from a Data Extension when making a retrieve request using WSProxy?

Something like a [LookupOrderedRows](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookuporderedrows.htm), but with SSJS WSProxy.

Comment: Is there a reason this has to be done with WSProxy, rather than the corresponding JavaScript LookupOrderedRows?

Answer (score 2):

Since the response being returned from your call will be an array of JS objects, you could just sort the response yourself with a simple function like (sorts alphabetically):

```
response.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.someKey.localeCompare(b.someKey);
});
```

The above would require that you had aggregated all of that data that you wished to sort but, with a sufficient filter applied to your WS Proxy retrieve call, that shouldn't be a huge issue.